# is it possible to connect to mysql database directly without rest api?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, rest

I'm very new to this backend stuff but I really want to know or else I can't sleep tonight or many other nightss.......

I'm tasked to build a rest API that will allow our web application to update our company's MySQL database remotely from any internet or client.

basically, the web application will be built using react framework that will allow users to take in some inputs and send them to the backend and update the MySQL database remotely.

so far, I have the rest API ready and inside this rest API i have included some mysql methods that will update the table in our database. it works fine.

but suddenly I couldn't find the reason why we need the rest API in the first place

below is the code I have...my question is

1. can't we just skip the express part? and directly connect the application to MySQL database using the mysql methods createConnection and then run db.query(sqlInsert) without running the app.get?
2. the only reason I can think of is that, if I do this, it will probably allow anyone to access the database from the browser's console. In this case, does it mean rest API is just like a filter that simply runs a server site after the user clicks the submit button, and then once the server runs it will then take the submitted information and run the db.query()? and then once that is complete, it will send back a response displayed on the server site saying its working?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({

    host:'the ip address of the computer that has the mySQL database',
    user: 'the user name created in workbench',
    password: 'the password created in workbench',
    database: 'the database name',
    port: '1234'

})

db.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
    console.log("connected to mysql")
})


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO  person123 (customerid, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('USv10', 'USv10', 'USv10');"
    db.query(sqlInsert), (err,  result) =>{
    }
    res.send('working')
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log ('running on port 3001 yes')
})
```

Comment: How do you intend to get user input without an http or some other kind of socket listener?

Comment: huge topic to answer.

Comment: @RaniSharim my idea was to just import the input values from the front end and directly use it in dq.query() after the connection is made with the database.

Comment: I don't understand how you think you'd get the data from the front end without any tcp socket open? What will get the data from my computer to yours?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can connect with mysql without express and running restful api but

condition is that server will be running using a specific port.with only this block

of code your server is connected to databse.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'the ip address of the computer that has the mySQL database',
    user: 'the user name created in workbench',
    password: 'the password created in workbench',
    database: 'the database name',
    port: '1234'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

and this block is nesecary for running server on specific port 
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log ('running on port 3001 yes')
})
```

Comment: i dont really understand, because if we run app.listen(3001, () => {....}, doesn't it mean that we have used express already?

my idea is, would it be possible to just import the variables from the front end and directly put it inside the db.query()?

Comment: you want to insert data at once ?? like hard codeed ?? for eg when you run project and insert data at once then you didn't need port . try concepts of seeders.